# Easy way to reduce prefab complexity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a simple way to reduce the complexity of prefabs that I'm using in Unity?  I notice that some prefabs I download are "Low Detail" which render far more quickly on my HoloLens device.  Other high quality prefabs don't do so well.  Is there a "slider" or something similar where I can adjust the quality of the prefab (or its underlying components like materials, textures, etc), without having to do work in Blender (outside of my skill set)?   I know the Unity project Quality Settings are helpful, but those settings impact the entire experience, instead of specific prefabs that are causing problems.  Thanks.

Comment: No, you must hire a studio to make different assets.  Your question would be much like asking "I saw a movie on the weekend and I want a different movie."

Comment: What you need is different "LOD" ("quality") set of prefabs, there's no workaround for that (except if you create your own meshes and prepare them, but as you mention prefabs, this is a different story I assume. Here's a doc page for a better understand: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic wand to fix objects. You need to learn a little about 3d modelling and Uvmapping.
Fast way to increase your frame rate and reduce render time and memory is doing a clean mesh with the fewest polygons posibble and minor texture size possible. Ever trying to use quads instead of triangles or ngons.
Uvmap texture also they influence in performance. Little textures = little resources to handle.
In the market are several softwares that can help you to reduce your mesh sacrifying quality, and each 3d software how 3d Max , Lightwave 3d, Cinema 4d, blender, etc have their own tools to reduce or clean mesh.
Sometimes is better a new retopology of your object than a reduce polygons algorithm for a clean mesh with low poly count.

Comment: (Your answer is correct of course but) quads?  what do you mean there?

Comment: @JoeBlow He probably means Quads: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_mesh#Quadrilateral

Comment: sure... mesh in Unity has only triangles. There is no quad concept in the pipeline. I guess, Jorel means that you can use abstraction tools in Maya etc., en route to your final lower poly models for use in Unity.  (Which can only be ordinary everyday triangle mesh.) In any event this is the correct answer - the first two sentences!

Comment: right @JoeBlow, in 3d models is better to use quadrilaterals polygons for smooth edges and easy uvmaping , but later their becom to be triangles. 1 quad = 2 triangles. A little reference: http://blog.digitaltutors.com/modeling-with-quads-or-triangles/

Comment: Hi Jorel.  Yes, we build mesh generation engines.  I'm not sure if you've ever used Unity3D as such.  There are **no** quads in the pipeline.  (Note that for the record, there are much, much more efficient heuristics than just converting each abstract quad to two triangles.)  Just as I said in the previous comment, I assume you mean use "quads" in Maya or the like, and let it reduce to tris for you for use in Unity. (Of course, pro low-poly artistes work at the triangle level for ultimate efficiency.)

Comment: @JoeBlow i understand you, Unity3d is a bad place to use how 3d model tool. Really the right explanation is to use 2 coplanars triangles, but i think is more easy to understand to use a quadrilateral polygon. Unity3d only work with triangle and all 3d software finally on render time convert all mesh to triangles internally. But if you add a simple 3d primitive box in Unity3d you can see that there is 6 quads...6x2 coplanar trianlges :)